# Uniqueness of the solution of $p_1(x)=p_2(x)e^{f(x)}$.

Tags: calculus

Consider an equation
$$x(x+1-2b)=(1-x)(2b-x)e^{a(x-b)}$$
where $x\in (0,1)$, $b\in (0,1)$ and $a>0$. $x=b$ is a solution of this equation for any $a$ and $b$. Let us fix $b$, I want to find for which values of $a$ this equation will have a unique solution. Obviously it has a unique solution for $a=0$. Moreover for $a>2/b(1-b)$ it is easy to show that this equation has to have at least 3 solutions (new solutions appearing close to $b$). 
The question is about $a<2/b(1-b)$ - it should have a unique solution (this comes from numerical calculations).

I tried to use some concave/convex argument but it failed.

Any help would be appreciated (what tools can help here, can you suggest where to search for similar results)

Comment: Did you mean to say, ' I want to find for which values of $a$ this equation will have a unique solution'?

Comment: Following up on Allawonder's comment, is it that you fix $b$ and then want the $a$ values in terms of $b$?

Comment: Yes. We fix $b$ and ask for which $a$ this equation has a unique solution $x=b$.